# How do i give parameters to SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, sonarqube, gitlab

From searching online and looking at sonarqube docs the only thing that I can find is:

```
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe /k:KeyOfProject /n:NameOfProject
msbuild.exe C:\projectpath\soultion.sln
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
```

The problem is there's no switches that i've found to set things like:

- analysis mode (preview, publish, increment/issues to set if sqube reports the project to server)
- how to make sonarqube comment on issues and code in Gitlab

The ONLY thing i can think of is by passing properties in the SonarQube.Analysis.xml but the syntax isn't clear for the sonar. properties.

```
 <Property Name="sonar.host.url">http://urlToYourServer.com</Property>
```

is a given, but everything is highly speculative. Does anyone actually know what they're doing? The documentation online just plain sucks.

Sources I've checked out :

- https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/tree/master/sonarqube-scanner-msbuild/CSharpProject
- https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the `/d:property=foo` syntax. For example, `/d:sonar.host.url=http://urlToYourServer.com` or `/d:"sonar.host.url=http://urlToYourServer.com"`

I have updated the [documentation of the Scanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner-for-dotnet/) so it will be easier for the next person.

Thanks for raising this!

Comment: The link to the documentation is dead (gives 404 Not Found), and the switches seem no longer valid.

Comment: New link: https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner-for-dotnet/
Sorry for that.